# Scala - Booleans - & vs &&, | vs ||

Tags: scala, boolean, operators

I just noticed that in Scala `Boolean` supports both `&` and `&&`. Is there a difference between these two operators? The Scala docs use the exact same description for both of them, so I wasn't sure.

Comment: Yes. Lazy/short-circuited (&&) and full (&) evaluation, just like Java.

Comment: @user2864740 Are you referring to short-circuiting?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

`&` and `|` are strict while `&&` and `||` are short-circuiting:

```
false && (throw new Exception()) => false
false & (throw new Exception()) => ex

true || (throw new Exception()) => true
true | (throw new Exception()) => ex
```

The full documentation for `&` and `|` have a note explaining this behaviour:

> This method evaluates both a and b, even if the result is already
>   determined after evaluating a.

Comment: Ah, didn't know you could expand the sections... missed the arrows entirely.