# Rewrite Scala && to and

Tags: scala

I am trying to rewrite Scala's `&&` to `and` in the following way (I love python, that's why I'm trying to do this):

```
def and(p1: () => Boolean, p2: () => Boolean): Boolean = p1() && p2()
```

However, when I try to use it with, e.g.:

```
def and(p1: () => Boolean, p2: () => Boolean): Boolean = p1() && p2()
if ((l < h.length) and (h(l) > h(i)))
```

(I put the `def` just on the line before only for debugging, to make sure it's not a visibility problem), I get:

```
Error:(40, 26) value and is not a member of Boolean
  if ((l < h.length) and (h(l) > h(i)))
```

What is going on here???

Comment: As indicated `and` is not a member of Boolean, defining that its first parameter is `() => Boolean` doesn't make it a member of the type `Boolean`

Comment: @cchantep - good point... so I have to somehow write an `implicit` to have `and` usable with `Boolean`?

Comment: Usually implicit conversion is too automagic and lessen the readability

Comment: Keep in mind that `and` and `&&` have different precedence. Changing one to the other could potentially change the meaning of your program. Probably not a good idea.

Comment: @AlvaroCarrasco - yes, indeed I noticed that the precedence would not be the same. Is there any way to manipulate the precedence of operators in Scala (I think not)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way to do what you want is something like this:

```
  object Pythonians {
    implicit class Bool(val b: Boolean) extends AnyVal { 
      def and(p: => Boolean) = b && p
    }
  }
```

Now you can do things like:

```
  import Pythonians._
  3 < 4 and "foo" == "bar"
```

But, do yourself a favor, and ... don't. 
If you "love python" so much, why don't you write code in python? If you are taking time to learn scala anyway, might as well give it's own syntax and idioms a try ... Who knows, maybe you'll grow to love it even more than you love python? 
And other people, who have to read the code you write will appreciate not having to figure out the whole new language too.

Comment: There is a problem here. I tried it, and it does not have the semantics of `&&` but rather the semantics of `&` :-)

Comment: @Frank I don't know what you are talking about. What is "semantics of &&" and what is "semantics of &"? `&` is a bitwise operator. I am not sure what you mean by "semantics", but this `and` is definitely not `&`.

Comment: Yes, `&` has the effect of evaluating both sides, whereas `&&` does not  evaluate the right hand side if the left hand side is false (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25067702/scala-booleans-vs-vs). The code provided above always evaluates both sides (I tried). To perfectly replace `&&`, it should not evaluate the right hand side if the left hand side evaluates to false.

Comment: @Frank no, it does not evaluate both sides. You "tried" something wrong :)

Comment: I take back my comment: I did a cut and paste of your code, and I do not see the evaluation of the right hand side anymore. I must have made an error somewhere (like using `() => Boolean` instead of `: => Boolean`, probably).

Answer (score 1):

With your definition, you'd call it as

```
and(() => l < h.length, () => h(l) > h(i))
```

Since the parameters have type `() => Boolean`, that's what you need to pass, not `Boolean`. Scala has special syntax to work around this called by-name parameters, which you can see in Dima's answer. Using it (but no implicit conversion), you'd write

```
def and(p1: => Boolean, p2: => Boolean): Boolean = p1 && p2
and(l < h.length, h(l) > h(i))
```

It means that you pass an expression of type `Boolean` as the argument, but it isn't calculated *before* calling the method, as usual, but at the place it's used. So in this case if `p1` evaluates to `false`, `p2` will never be evaluated, just like `&&`.

Comment: That is not what I am observing - or I made a mistake somewhere. I used that code and got a bug related to evaluating the left and right hand side of that `and`. I'll go back to double check, I must have made a mistake somewhere.

Comment: See above, I made a mistake in syntax initially.